# Moodle over dedicated server suddenly stopping

Tags: moodle

moodle suddenly stops over a cloud server
I migrated my cloud to GoDaddy's Dedicated server it was working fine but today moodle suddenly is stopping and then going online again the stop lasts between 30 sec and 2 minutes and then it reconnects what could be the problem?

Comment: Please use punctuation, post is hard to read. What is OS that Moodle is runing on? Database, web server,  php version? Maybe web server is restarting, what says web server log?

Comment: CentOS7, Mysql 5.7, Apache 2.4.43, I don't think the webserver is restarting since in the time the model disconnects another page on the same web server was still running normally.

Comment: php, moodle version? If everything is according system requirements and other virtual hosts don't have problem, check the moodle httpd log. There must be something. Check the database. If it was working fine what has changed? Update, changed configuration, installed new packages? Go trough logs, try to find point when it started. When you say `moodle suddenly is stopping`, what do you mean: it is unreachable from your browser, did you try from other locations?

Comment: Moodle 3.8, PHP 7.3, nothing is changed from the first we installed Moodle, the database log file doesn't show anything at the time of the incidents, no new installation package the whole cloud is for the moodle. moodle suddenly is stopping means it stops and the refresh button keeps loading until the 30s - 2 minutes frame (No error page is displayed on browser).

Comment: how can I check the moodle httpd log I couldn't find it, also if it's worth it at the time the apache error log doesn't show anything related to it.

Comment: `the whole cloud is for the moodle` and `another page on the same web server was still running normally`, which one is correct? Check httpd virtual host configuration, there should be set destionation of log files for moodle (error and access log). If it is not set, everything should  be logged in /var/log/httpd/acces.log (and error.log). From your browser using developer tools check if you can get something useful.

Comment: the whole cloud is for a moodle, the other page is just a testing page about-us, ill check the logs and report back.